# Pre-loading questions and logic flow?

Tags: docassemble

I have an interview using the mandatory code block approach (i.e. where the mandatory code block tells DA which questions to ask, as here: https://docassemble.org/docs/logic.html#bplogic).

Everything has been going swimmingly, except now I am trying to determine if a question should be asked, based on the value generated by the preceding question using `states_list()` (https://docassemble.org/docs/functions.html#states_list).

So I have something like this:

```
---
mandatory: True
code: |

   country_code = country

   ask_for_state = bool(states_list(country_code))

   if ask_for_state:
      state
```

You can see I've gone down the rabbit-hole because I'm using `bool()` to define `ask_for_state`. his works fine for most countries (the US, Canada, France, the UK, etc.), so `state` is being defined correctly. What's weird/unexpected is that even though `ask_for_state` is `false` in the raw data (`"ask_for_state": false`), I'm still getting the question for `state` popping up right after selecting `country`.

All I can think is that DA is "pre-queuing" the question, so that when it's asking for `country`, it has already decided it's going to ask for `state`.

Not the behavior I want, because for example **Saint Pierre and Michelon** have no states, so you get really weird behavior in terms of the way the question displays (it essentially asks you to select a state from a null list, not to mention `subdivision_type(country)` displays "None".

Wondering if anyone can lend any insight?

PS - I also noticed an issue where `subdivision_type()` for Singapore returns 'division' with a lower-case 'd', which is sort of weird because "State," "Province," etc. all come in with the first letter capitalized.

**Edit (2022-Jul-16):** I feel silly... later on, I was accidentally asking for `state`. Always nice to have a second set of eyes, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the question for `state` shows, you could press the `</>` button to see the explanation of "How question came to be asked." It might be that the need for `state` was triggered by something other than your `mandatory` `code` block.

In the following interview, the Mako `if` statement ensures that the question for `user_state` is not asked if the country doesn't have subdivisions.

```
question: |
  In which country do you live?
fields:
  - Country: user_country
    code: countries_list()
    default: US
---
question: |
  Where do you live?
fields:
  - State: user_state
    code: states_list(country_code=user_country)
---
mandatory: True
question: |
  Your country is ${ country_name(user_country) }.
  % if len(states_list(country_code=user_country)) > 0:
  You live in
  ${ state_name(user_state, country_code=user_country) },
  which is abbreviated
  ${ user_state }.
  % endif
```

Comment: Thank you. It's definitely being triggered by my mandatory code block... edited the question accordingly. Wondering if it's possible that it has something to do with using the `Address` object?

Comment: It works as expected. My brain just doesn't sometimes :)